# A Romance Novel Featuring Time Travel

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, romantic-interest

I'm looking for a book that I read in middle school. My memory of it is a bit fuzzy but hopefully someone can help me.

It involves a high school girl who I believe was a witch or something. There was also a boy who was shy and sort of lanky and she didn't really like him. I believe she wished for something, and because of that wish the boy ended up in the medieval time period. It may not make a lot of sense but someone might know this plot a little bit and have read it.

She has to go back in time to find the boy within so many days or else I think they will both be stuck in that period. She finds him and they have to journey back to somewhere to get to the present. She ends up getting to like him during the journey because of how he's changed during the time he was in the medieval time period. I think a princess was involved too and he was guard or something.

Anyway they get to the present and she finds out that he likes her and she likes him and I think they go to the dance together and you know...live happily ever after.

But if this sounds even remotely similar to any books that you've read please let me know.

Comment: Can you tell us roughly when you were in middle school? Where you got the book (borrowed from a friend, school library, other)? Any memories about the cover? Please edit any information into the question. If it helps - the first author I think of when you're talking about SF&F with witches and teens and a touch of romance would be Andre Norton.